# Split taxonomies on different pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, terms

I'm working on a Woocommerce website and created a new taxonomy `activity`. I've added that taxonomy to the post type Product.

So a Product can have one of the following `activity`:

1. Museum
2. Food & Drinks
3. Attractions
4. Guided tours

To show all the Products, I've created `taxonomy-activity.php` which already shows all the products that have an activity taxonomy.

But I have to have all the Products with taxonomy Guided tours on a seperate page. And all the others on the other page. So there will be 2 pages: One page will be called Guided tours which only shows the guided tours and the other is called Activities.

Is it correct to do this with the taxonomy-{slug}.php or should I create a new page. For example: `page-guidedtours.php` which loops through all the Product with Guided tours taxonomy. And the other page `page-activities.php` which loops through all the Products without Guided tours taxonomy.

Sidenote: I'm using the plugin FacetWP in order to show the Product and created filters. So the query is created with the plugin and then the list of products in shown with a shortcode.

My current query is:

```
<?php
return [
   "post_type" => [
   "product"
],
   "post_status" => [
   "publish"
],
   "posts_per_page" => "18",
   "orderby" => "title",
   "order" => "ASC",
];
```

I'm thinking about created 2 Facets. One facet that shows the Guided tours. So in this case I have to add the term Guided tours to the query. And then other facet without the term Guided tours.

Answer (score 0):

> To show all the Products, I've created taxonomy-activity.php which already shows all the products that have an activity taxonomy.

That's not what `taxonomy-activity.php` is for. That template is the template that is used for displaying posts for each activity taxonomy *term*. So if you view Museum activity, that template will be used to display all Museum products, or if you view the Food & Drink activity the same template will be use to view Food & Drink products.

The template itself should not be choosing which posts to display. WordPress has already done that. All this template should be used for is *presenting* those posts. To loop through the products that WordPress has already query, you need to just use [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/), not a custom query:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        // Display product content
    endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

So WordPress will automatically make an archive available for each activity taxonomy which displays products that belong to it. You should not need to create a page or template for each one.

The same applies to post types. When you register a post type, like Products, it WordPress will automatically make an archive of all Products available if `has_archive` is set to `true` or a slug. To create a unique template for this archive, you need to create `archive-product.php`. This will then automatically be used at `https://example.com/products/`, where `products` is the post type name, or the slug pass to `has_archive`.

So what you need is `archive-product.php` which will be used when viewing all products at something like `https://example.com/products/`, and `taxonomy-activity.php` which will be used when viewing each activity links like `https://example.com/activity/museum/` or `https://example.com/activity/attractions/`, as examples.

When is comes to adding FacetWP support for filtering these archives, you will need to consult their documentation, since 3rd-party plugins are off topic here, but when it comes to the required built in WordPress templates you need them set up like I described as a starting point.